# WPF custom control renders incorrectly

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I'm creating a pivot like control in wpf, but I have an issue with the header of the control. It only shows up when I resize the window, probably because the header control is not yet measured when the pivot control is rendered.
I'm probably forgetting something or doing something wrong, but I just can't find out what it is.

I created a solution to demonstrate then problem. You can download it here http://cid-25374d9051083633.office.live.com/self.aspx/Code/WpfApplication6.zip

Does anyone have a solution to this problem or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't looked at the attachment, but are you binding to the window size? Are you specifying window sizes? If not these will be `NaN`.

Comment: No, I'm not binding to width or height. These are just specified in MainWindow.xaml. The controls template contains a grid with two rows. The header control is in row0 and row0's height is set to 'Auto'.

Comment: The project seems to be missing PivotHeaderCategoriesControl and PivotHeader which are referenced in generic.xaml

Comment: I removed the references to the two control that were missing. I used them before, but reduced the problem to these four controls that are in the solution now. Th link is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a few problems with your code, I haven't managed to get it working but this is what I've noticed.

You probably want to create a dependency property on your pivot control that you can template bind, in Generic.xaml, to your PivotHeaderItemsControl.

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> Headers
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(HeadersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeadersProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Headers.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeadersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Headers", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(Pivot), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

Also your templates for your ItemsControls don't seem right, you have wrapped you ItemsPresenter in grids but this will mean each item in the ItemsSource will be layered on top of each other. If you wrap the ItemsPresenter in a StackPanel or something similar all the items should appear.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If you update your sample I can take another look.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact the items will be layered on top of each other, but I did this to rule out the possibility that the fault was in my custom panel.

Comment: The solution referenced in the original post now contains a dependency property for Headers, but the problem still exists.

Comment: I've gone through all the XAML in blend and it looks fine. If I comment out the if statement on OnItemsChanged in Pivot, the header then renders fine. I suspect what is happening is that RefreshHeaderCollection is being called to late when the view is rendered so that the header isn't displayed until you resize the window. By removing the if statement it allows that method to be called earlier allowing the header to be correctly displayed.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it and it works, but when I add for example a child to the Pivot in MainWIndow.xaml that has not yet a container then this fails, because RefreshHeaderCollection calls ItemcontainerGenerator.COntainerFromIndex(i) which returns null because there is not yet a container created. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You might need to update your sample, I don't quite follow. What sort of child are you adding to pivot?

Comment: I updated my sample. The change is in Mainwindow.xaml. Previously the Pivot control had only PivotItem childs, but now I added a Button which should be automatically be wrapped in a PivotItem container. Now, if you remove the check in OnItemsChanged it doesn't work anymore because the container is not yet generated.

Comment: Tom, are you still looking into this issue? Otherwise I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I did have another but couldn't spend too much time on it. It seems like there could be a couple issues in RefreshHeaderCollection.